# Datastore: Saved vs Retrieved (Datetime values)

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore

**Hi everybody!**

I'm using NodeJS client library to save some datetimes and other values in datastore.

In GCP shows:
[image]

But when I get that values ("fecDocumento" and "fecRegistro" ). This returns:

```
- fecDocumento: 1517806800000000
- fecRegistro: +050068-07-10T00:16:40.000Z
```

If I convert that values to Date vars. The values printed are:

```
- fecDocumento: Fri May 20 50067 03:00:00 GMT-0500 (Hora est. Pacífico, Sudamérica)
- fecRegistro: Mon Jul 09 50068 19:16:40 GMT-0500 (Hora est. Pacífico, Sudamérica)
```

Any suggestion will be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fecDocumento` seems to be a unix timestamp in microseconds, most date-time libraries expect a unix timestamp to be in milliseconds or seconds. It looks like your value is getting multiplied on its way out

1517806800 (unix timestamp in seconds) Is equivalent to: 02/05/2018 @ 5:00am (UTC)

https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php

Comment: In addition to @Alex 's answer: fecRegistro appears to also have been already converted from a microseconds reference value using an standard second-based Unix timestamp.

If there is any configuration you can change in your fetch routine, it would fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Alex.
I had to extract the first thirteen characters and casting a Date object. Doing this I get correct value.